Listing pods associated with a deployment
How do I get a list of all pods associated with a deployment? In the GUI, it's as simple as clicking on the deployment and checking the pods tab. However, I can't find a way using the CLI.
I've tried using a script that uses string matching to check if the pod name begins with the deployment name, but it's not really sufficient due to the possibility of deployments beginning with the same string.

The Pod names always begin with the Deployment name, and the most common trick I've seen is simply kubectl get pod | grep deployment-name.

Thanks @DavidMaze My issue is that I'm administrating a cluster with thousands and thousands of pods/deployments. I feel like this method would cause issues if for example a deployment was called 'my-deployment' and one was called 'my-deployment-test'. If I were to do oc get pods | grep 'my-deployment', it would return pods that aren't associated with that deployment

Typically you would select Pods using labels. You can check what labels your Pods have using the following command:
oc get pods --show-labels
kubectl get pods --show-labels

Then you can select Pods based on a label (likely your Deployments have custom labels):
oc get pods -l "app=myapp"
kubectl get pods -l "app=myapp"

Alternatively you could figure out the matching Deployment / ReplicaSet via the .metadata.ownerReferences field, but that is a lot more involved. Using a label is significantly easier.

Hmm. Thanks for your help @Simon but that might not work for me. In my case, I'm a cluster admin and I'm not responsible for a lot of the pods running on my cluster, project admins are. A lot of them don't have labels on their pods that match their deployments' label. Was hoping there was a way to list the pods that are in the 'pods' tab of the deployment view in the GUI. There must be something that links them in the GUI...

Are you sure they don't have labels? Something connects the Deployment to its pods. What do you see in the Deployment's YAML spec.selector?

@dbreaux you're correct they do have labels that match them, but I've found examples where the label name that associates a pod with a deployment is different for different deployments & pods. So in my case where I'm creating a script that has to list all pods associated with a deployment, I'm not too sure how I would cover all bases, ensuring every possible label that associates a pod with a deployment is checked.

@dbreaux I've also just found an example where a deployment doesn't have any labels, but the pod tab in the GUI shows two pods associated with it

@Simon Turns out ownerReferences is the way to go. Tracing back from pod to replicaset/replicationcontroller to deployment/deploymentconfig seems like the only solid way

I'm still curious what's in spec.selector.

A pod will be selected by the deployment using labels.
To determine the labels used by the deployment, use:
$ kubectl get deployments -n {namespace} {deployment} -o jsonpath="{.spec.selector.matchLabels}" | jq .
This will output (for me, using my prometheus kibana deployment):
{
  "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "prometheus",
  "app.kubernetes.io/name": "grafana"
}

You then use these labels to select the pods from the same namespace:
$ kubectl get pods -n prometheus -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=prometheus,app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana
...
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
prometheus-grafana-6ffd599f89-m8mks   0/3     Pending   0          6h42m

Note that you use all the labels, separated by comma, and use "=" instead of ":"

To see all the pods under Deployments you need to:

login to the cluster (get the login token from the console):
oc login --token=sha256~bZ-gWbOP2WMzXXXXXy472cMg-XXXXXXXXXX --server=https://api.cluster-name.domain.com:6443

if you want to see all pods running, on all projects:
oc get pods --all-namespaces

if you want to see all pods on a given project, say project cert-manager:
oc get pods -n cert-manager

if you want to see all pods on a given project with details:
oc get pods -n cert-manager -o wide


